# Counting variables that are missing by group in SAS

Tags: sas, grouping, counting

I am not sure how to do what I want. Basically I have a group variable of organizations I am interested in, I would like to look across the data set see how many variables are empty for each organization.

So like data I have:

```
ORG Var1    Var2    Var3
OrgA    .   1   0
OrgB    1   1   0
OrgC    .   .   .
```

Want:

```
ORG Count of Missing Var
OrgA    1
OrgB    0
OrgC    3
```

I have about 40 organizations in the group variable and about 200 variables total.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome :-)

I think this is what you want:

```
data have;
input ORG $ Var1 Var2 Var3;
datalines;
OrgA . 1 0 
OrgB 1 1 0 
OrgC 0 . . 
;

data want;
   set have;
   array var Var:;
   num_miss = nmiss(of var[*]);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of variables, use the special variable list specifiers `_NUMERIC_` and `_CHARACTER_` to process them.

```
num_miss_count = nmiss(of _numeric_);
char_miss_count = cmiss(of _character_);
```